# Retrieving the answer of a deleted question

Tags: support

I provided an answer to this deleted question: [Calculating power function for ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80048/calculating-power-function-for-anova).
I was looking for my answer and that's how I've discovered the question has been deleted. Is there a way to retrieve my answer ? It took me a non-short time to write it, and I'm sad cause I need it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to do this for users with less than 10K reputation. (I'll try to look into this some more.)

In the meantime, I do not see why the question was deleted in the first place, so I have undeleted it. You should also now be able to access your answer.

Comment: Thank you @cardinal!

Comment: I have noticed that I cannot delete my own question that has an answer unless I flag it. This must mean that the moderators took it down?

Comment: @MHH: You cannot delete your own question if it has *upvoted* answers. In the case at hand, the answer in question had no votes when the original OP decided to delete it.